# How to get browser to ignore one row when computing table width

Tags: html, html-table

Say I have a table with one column per row, where the cells contain text.  One of the rows has much longer text than the others.  I'd like to display a table where that row is not taken into consideration when the table width is computed; that is, the width would be the same as if that long row were removed.  The long text would then be wrapped over several lines.

Example:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>tabtest</title>
      <style type="text/css">
         #tab1 { border-style: solid; border-collapse: collapse }
         table#tab1 td { border-style: solid; border-width : 1px;
                         padding: 5px }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table id="tab1">
         <tr><td>Veni, vidi, vici</td></tr>
         <tr><td>All's well that ends well</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Let them eat cake</td></tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

This makes the table width the entire width of the browser window (with the really long text wrapping over 3 lines).  This isn't what I want.  I'm trying to get it displayed so that the table width is based on the second row (the longest of the remaining three rows).  The third row would then wrap over many lines (which is ugly, but it won't be so bad in the real-life example I'm working on).

I've tried various combinations of `width: inherit`, `width: 100%`, `word-wrap: break-word`, either in the `<td>` for the long row or in singly- or doubly-nested `<div>` elements inside that cell, but I haven't gotten anything to do what I want.